# Interprocess communication using sockets between windows service and form app

Tags: windows, winforms, sockets, service, ipc

I need to send command to windows service from a windows form. I have tried ExecuteCommand of ServiceController but had hard time testing.

I am planning to use sockets for IPC as i can also receive a feedback.

If any one could help find a similar example it would be great.

thanks.

Comment: Usually for IPC like this I prefer plain sockets.  They're simple and easy to test (just telnet/ncat to try out).  However a gotcha is you have to choose a listening port that could potentially cause conflicts.  I prefer a random port for this reason.

Comment: Remoting?  It can really bi simple, if you don't expect much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

I decided to go with wcf and [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) really helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind third-party solution, our MsgConnect ( http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/ ) was designed for exactly your purpose and it has a sample. With MsgConnect you can use MMF or sockets as a transport.